# Where to save Game Scores, Last Level Passed, etc.? Parse(Cloud backend) or Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, game-center

*noob to iOS and Game Dev*

I am writing a simple game which has incremental levels (flow chart below). Only thing that I want to do it save information like "Last level passed" on to the cloud.

I would like it so that whether the user signs in to my app from iOS, Android, Web (I'm starting off with iOS app only) - always goes back to the right level.

My *fundamental architecture question* - should I saving this information in somewhere on Facebook API/SDK or in my own Cloud Backend? (I'm using Parse as my backend)

[image: Game Flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save it into Parse so that you are not tied to Facebook for your users. I know many people do not want to connect their Facebook accounts to apps, etc. so this way you can have one solution for everyone.

Also, by using your own backend you can use Facebook a way for users to log in and then later allow them to log in via twitter, etc. and your game would still work as it should regardless of how the user chose to create an account.

Comment: Do you know what do the big boys (Candy Crush, Angry Birds, etc) do? Do they use only for the login and friends connection system and all custom game data is saved in their own cloud? (I'm not in the industry so just trying to be aware of the standard practices)

Comment: Since you do not have to connect to facebook to play candy crush, I assume they just use it to access your friends list, post to your account and as an authentication system (log in) but store all the account data, etc. in their own backend system (could be parse, but not sure).

Comment: Candy Crush makes over a billion dollars a year. On these volumes, it may be cheaper to run your own backend than to use Parse.  In the mean time, Parse can score game levels and retrieve game levels in a few lines of boilerplate code, supports a huge range of platforms, has pre-built log in screens for facebook, google etc, good backend database maintenance through web screens, works very well, and is free or cheap for low to medium volumes.